# Does Windows XP support TLS1.1 with AES256?

Tags: windows, security

Is TLS 1.1 support included in Windows XP SP3?

Comment: This does not qualify as a programming question, although I have answered it.

Answer (score 2):

No TLS 1.1 support is included only in Windows Vista.